# Objective-C API for creating Mail/Message like receivers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, badge

Does anyone know if there exists an open Apple API to use to create rounded receivers badges as you can see in both Mail and Message app (and probably several other Apple apps).

EDIT: An examplifying picture (I want to achieve the same effect as where it says "Jay Deragon")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:99] //shows 99 on app icon
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for. Rather, he's interested in finding how to draw the blue button / field used for From: addresses.

Comment: I missed that, sorry, my apologies.